# javascripts version of jquery.data()

Tags: javascript, html

if I add data like this

```
function create(htmlStr){
    var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(),
    temp = document.createElement('div');
    temp.innerHTML = htmlStr;
    while (temp.firstChild){
        frag.appendChild(temp.firstChild);
        }
    return frag;
    }

var el=document.getElementsByClassName('b'+M)[0];

el.appendChild(create('<div data-what="whatinthewhatnow"></div>'));
```

I can see it in the 'right click > inspect element console'.

is this normal i thought all data-* attributes were suppose to be hidden from user view?

ps: I can't use jquery.data (not allowed :) ).

Comment: *Nothing* on the client is hidden. Nothing.

Comment: @user2736012 jquery.data() is hidden!

Comment: ***Nothing on the client is hidden. Nothing.*** Everything can be found. jQuery.data is stored in `jQuery.cache`, and it's trivial to find it.

Comment: oh. i did not know that. that makes things easy for hackers!

Comment: Yes... sort of. Once you know that everything is exposed, then you also know that anything remotely secure must take place on the server, not the client. One caveat to my above comments. HTTP-only cookies aren't available to JavaScript, though they're still vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attacks, and the data can be seen in the console. If your concern is the person at their own computer seeing something, then best to simply not send it. If your concern is hackers, then you can get a bit more security, depending on what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data attributes aren't hidden from the code inspector, but then again, nothing is - that's a debugging tool, and all JavaScript is available to all users to see - just by clicking "view source", and if necessary following any links and doing the same.

However, data attributes officially can't impact the web browser, so they aren't rendered or treated in any other way that makes them visible to the user.

Here's what the [w3 specification](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#custom-data-attribute) has to say about the custom data attribute (highlighting added by me)

> Custom data attributes are intended to store custom data private to the page or application, for which there are no more appropriate attributes or elements.
>
> These attributes are not intended for use by software that is independent of the site that uses the attributes.
>
> ... these attributes are intended for use by the site's own scripts, and are not a generic extension mechanism for publicly-usable metadata.
>
> ...**User agents must not derive any implementation behavior from these attributes or values.** Specifications intended for user agents must not define these attributes to have any meaningful values.
>
> JavaScript libraries may use the custom data attributes, as they are considered to be part of the page on which they are used.

Also, you may want to read [John Resig's post about the data attributes](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/#postcomment).  It's 5 years old, and out of date in that he says "no browsers support `.dataset`, and now they all do, but otherwise a very worthwhile (and short) read.   (If you don't know, John Resig is the guy responsible for writing jQuery.)